# How to convert a feed url into an actual XML file?

Tags: xml, csv

I have a feedlink that leads to a really really long xml file that I need to convert to CSV. I've tried copy and pasting the entire feed and pasting it to notepad then saving it as a .xml but when I try to convert to csv it says that the feed is invalid. Is there anything I can use like tools to turn a feed link into a xml file?

Comment: The title is wrong. You ask for a XML file although you have already a XML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can not convert a XML file to CSV, because a XML file is a tree and a CSV file is a matrix. If you have a special crafted XML file, which contains two dimensional data, you can write a XSLT file, which can be used to extract the tabular data. But there is no generic way to do so.